# nextjs has some exclusive functionality for vercel only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm migrating all my applications to  nextjs framework! and I would like to know, if all the functionality of nextjs is possible to replicate on private dockers servers or any type of jamstack itself or some functionality is limited only to the vercel platform

Comment: To get a non-static site in Next setup is not straight forward and there a lot of different pieces of the hosting puzzle.  This repository will shed light on the a potential AWS setup and may also save you a lot of time  - https://github.com/dealmore/terraform-aws-next-js

Comment: thank for contribuition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can replicate all the functionality of nextjs in private applications such as docker k8s among others, being necessary to create apis for communications with framework like cache control another or stack clustering to deploy high availability among other clustering practices cdn reverse proxy and clearly many solutions  like continuous deployment and  continuous delivery! the diference is the  vercel delivers ready for your frontend serverless and global cdn